# jQuery how to center image vertically and horizontally a.k.a. image lightbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b6CyG/1/)

```
  $(document).ready (function(){
    $("a").click(function(){
            $(".myCanvas").fadeIn();
            $(".myCanvas").html ($(this).html());               
    }); 
});
```

`a` is an image link. Is it possible eto put a `$(this).css({});` inside the `$(this.html)`? What I am trying to do is when i click the image i want the image to appear in the middle of the webpage with a transparent black background behind it to cover the other images without using Fancybox and lightbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go dude:

http://jsfiddle.net/mattdlockyer/SyJSS/1/

CSS:

```
#img-container {
    position:fixed;
    display:none;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-top:-50px;
    margin-left:-100px;
    z-index:9999;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.img').on('click', function (e) {
    $('#img-cover').fadeIn();
    var img = $(this);
    $('#img-container').html(img.clone())
        .css({
        'margin-top': '-' + img.height() / 2 + 'px',
            'margin-left': '-' + img.width() / 2 + 'px'
    }).fadeIn();
});

$('#img-cover').on('click', function () {
    $('#img-cover').fadeOut();
    $('#img-container').fadeOut();
});
```

Source: http://css-tricks.com/quick-css-trick-how-to-center-an-object-exactly-in-the-center/

Opinion: use libraries. There are usually some lightweight ones that will account for browser compatibility. It's a pain to roll your own solution all the time.

Comment: Sir how can you make it not to disappear from the back page. I tried it using 2 images. Whenever i click the image it disappears from the website and displays in the middle. Thank you

Comment: Updated fiddle and code, this should do what you're looking for. Please accept my title edit as well since it makes the question more clear and the solution more valuable.

Comment: sir just a follow up question... in the last part is $('#img-cover'||'#img-container).on('click', function ()... so if either the cover or the container was clicked, they both have the same function of hiding them. is || accepted in jquery? Thank you Sir

Comment: No use a comma, your selector will be $('#img-cover, #img-container')

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/c84vD/) is a fiddle with a solution.  Click on an image (colored block) to open `myCanvas` and populate it with the selected image.  Click anywhere in `myCanvas` to hide it and select another image.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="images_box">
        <a><img style="background: red;" /></a>
         <a><img style="background: blue;" /></a>
         <a><img style="background: green;" /></a>
         <a><img style="background: black;" /></a>
         <a><img style="background: pink;" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="myCanvas"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 80%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    height: 300px;
    /*background: #123;*/
}
.images_box {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
}
img {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 5px;
}
.myCanvas {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background: #999;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a').click(function () {
        $('.myCanvas').fadeIn();
        $('.myCanvas').html($(this).html());
        $('.myCanvas').children().css('display', 'block');
        $('.myCanvas').children().css({
            'margin-left': 'auto',
            'margin-right': 'auto'
        });

        var topMargin = 125;

        $('.myCanvas').children().css('margin-top', topMargin);
    });

    $('.myCanvas').click(function () {
        $('.myCanvas').fadeOut();
    });
});
```

It takes the image (copies the html to `myCanvas`) and then centers it.

Comment: It's just an example.  You can take all the widths and heights and change them, or modify the script to make them dynamic.  It's just a proof of concept.  And only hard value is `topMargin` in the JS code, and that can easily be changed to a dynamic value calculated from the div widths and heights.